# Create a method to check the winner

Tags: c#, winforms

I have developed a tic tac toe using win form in visual studio c# express. I want to create a method that should check for winner and if winner not found and all the blocks are over we have a message to show draw.

But i want it to be form independent.
like i have tried such equations

```
if((button1.Text== button2.Text) && (button2.Text== button3.Text))
else if((button4.Text== button5.Text) && (button5.Text== button6.Text))
else if((button7.Text== button8.Text) && (button8.Text== button9.Text))
```

i want a general logic so that i can create that method in another class and call

Comment: Could you clarify what you exactly want to do? Because as far as I understood your question you just need to pass these values to a class and check them there...

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment to me. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your current code uses class fields, which stops you from using the code with any other form. So instead of having:

```
bool CheckWinner() { }
```

You'll need to supply the game data as a parameter:

```
bool CheckWinner(Button topLeftButton, Button topMiddleButton, ...) { }
```

Then, you may someday decide that you won't be using `Button`s, and you'd change your method to:

```
bool CheckWinner(string topLeftValue, string topMiddleValue, ...) { }
```

You may also want to consider using an `enum`:

```
enum TicTacToeValue
{
    None = 0,
    Cross = 1,
    Circle = 2,
}

bool CheckWinner(TicTacToeValue topLeft, TicTacToeValue topMiddle, ...) { }
```

or even supply an array of those to your method:

```
bool CheckWinner(TicTacToeValue[] values) { }
```

When using such an array you make your program a bit more intelligent, because you can reuse code that checks for a full row or column of values.

You can even return *who* won:

```
TicTacToeValue GetWinner(TicTacToeValue[] values) { }
```

Which can return `TicTacToeValue.None` if no one has won sofar.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
public bool IsThreeInARow(string v1, string v2, string v3)
{
    return v1 == v2 && v2 == v3;
}
```

This will check one row of values (i.e. X-s and/or O-s), independent of where the values came from.

Answer (score -2):

Make nine static flags for nine buttons that you have and set them 1 or 0 for 'x' and '0'.

Use those flags in other class to determine the winner. Don't need to access the tic tac toe buttons.